# Why does Kafka have a higher throughput than Redis?

Tags: apache-kafka, redis, messagebroker

Studies suggest Kafka has overall better throughput both in msgs per second as well as mbs transferred/s if compared to redis when they both act as a message broker.

A recent study named "a comparison of data ingestion platforms in real-time stream processing pipelines" shows kafka can handle up to 3 times the amount of requests/s than redis for a 1kB payload.

What exactly makes Kafka so much more powerful/faster than redis as a message broker?

Comment: 1) All benchmarks should be done in your own environment. 2) Unless you have subject matter experts in each of the tested softwares, there are subtle configuration changes that can drastically change the results in favor of one or another 3) Do some research into Kafka's "zero copy" mechanisms

Answer (score 1):

Kafka’s throughput performance is based on the combination of the number of producers, the consumer, and the replication method.
I suggest you take a look at [this article](https://logz.io/blog/kafka-vs-redis/) if you need more info.